# My DataGridView malfunction when i click Print Button

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, printing, datagridview

[image: MY DATAGRID]    Whenever i click Print Button, my datagridview malfunction,

This is my PRINT BUTTON Code:

```
Dim width As Integer = DataGridView1.Width

DataGridView1.Height = DataGridView1.RowCount * DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height
Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height)
DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height))
PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
DataGridView1.Width = Width
```

This is my code on PRINTDOCUMENT1

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)

Dim rectPrint As RectangleF = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea

'change height to width if printing in landscape mode
If Me.DataGridView1.Width - rectPrint.Width > 0 Then e.HasMorePages = True

PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
```

Comment: *"my datagridview malfunction"* is as much use as *"it doesn't work"*, which is to say that it's no use at all.  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try, including how what happens differs from your expectations.

Comment: Why are you changing the DataGridView height at the start of the procedure? What was the height before?